# AngularJS : Can't init with ng-init via Ajax

Tags: angularjs

HTML:

```
<div class="span10" ng-controller="GroupFieldsCntl" ng-init="init()">
    <div ng-repeat="field in fields"></div>
</div>
```

GroupFieldCntl:

```
function GroupFieldsCntl($scope) {
    $scope.fields = [];

    $scope.init = function() {
            // Get fields.
        $.get(ctx + 'admin/fields/fieldsJSON', function(data) {
            for(var i in data) {
                $scope.fields.push(data[i]);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I'm sure the ajax call get correct response, but the html page doesn't display those data.

Comment: Not an answer but you might want to check `hasOwnProperty` too when using `for(var i in data)`.

Comment: Use angular's `$http` instead of jquery's $.get().

Comment: @CodeHater, I just don't understand, I thought any change to `$scope.fields` should effect html page.

Comment: Anything you do inside $.get() is outside angular world where it cannot track any changes to the models. Go with `$http`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the commentors here say:
1. Use $http.get instead of $.get. This is Angular's Ajax and you should be using it. [it needs to be injectecd into the controller]
2. If you loop in `var i in data` you might loop through methods of non-data properties, so as was suggested, use

```
for (var i in data) {
    if data.hasOwnProperty(i)
       //do something
    }
}
```

And if you don't think there will be issues with bad data, you can always use the following syntax to have the resolved promise (get request) resolve itself to the $scope variable:

```
$scope.fields = $http.get(tx + 'admin/fields/fieldsJSON');
```

When the data arrives fields will automatically contain the JSON response after it was resolved. This is a shortcut which doesn't handle error responses though.

Answer (score 0):

The changes done to data will trigger view changes only if you do it with `angular` functions or use `$apply` on other functions. So as the comments suggest you can (should) either use angular's `$http` service, or call your function inside `$apply`.